# How to choose base classifier in ensembles?

Tags: python, ensemble-learning, java

Recently, I have come through some papers, in which we could find a statement like this:

"We choose Hoeffding Classifier as the base classifier, and k=15 is set for the ensemble"..

According to my exposure, different algorithms could be used in an ensemble and a voting mechanism could be adapted. How can we use one same classifier in an ensemble for 15 times.? For example here:

[https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~abifet/MOA/API/_oza_bag_8java_source.html](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/%7Eabifet/MOA/API/_oza_bag_8java_source.html)

Its using Hoeffding classifier by default. Could a classifier learn itself differently if called 2 times on same data??

Tx.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [API documentation](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/%7Eabifet/MOA/API/classmoa_1_1classifiers_1_1meta_1_1_oza_bag.html#details) for the code you linked to, it's an implementation of [Oza and Russel (2001) Online Bagging and Boosting](http://proceedings.mlr.press/r3/oza01a.html). This is an online algorithm that randomly selects one classifier, according to a $\text{Poisson}(1)$ distribution over the classifier index, to update for each training instance. Each of the base classifiers is therefore trained on a different partition of the data. The random choice is made in `trainOnInstanceImpl` of the code you linked.

Comment: Could a classifier learn itself differently if called 2 times on the same data??

Comment: If it has some random component, sure. For example, a model with a non convex loss can converge to a different local optimum if it starts from a different random initialization, even if the data are the same. However, in the code you have linked, the base classifiers are not trained in the same data: for each data point, only one classifier is updated

Comment: Does it make sense if Algorithm1 uses a single base classifier in ensemble whereas, Algorithm2 uses 2,3 different base classifiers in its ensemble, and their performance comparison is drawn on a dataset? It could be done, obviously, but will it be a fair comparison in that case.?